# DigitalOcean Droplet IP address not working

Tags: node.js, digital-ocean, droplet

I created my first droplet, but when I try to navigate to the provided IP address like `http://my_ip_address`, it shows `This site can’t be reached` in the browser.

[This](https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-host-a-node-js-app-on-digital-ocean) is the tutorial I used to create the droplet, and I got my web app from github.

Do I also need to install a webserver like Apache? The tutorial didn't say anything about needing to do that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Port 3000 is blocked by Digital Oceans firewall. Available ports are 22, 80 and 443. You could also try

```
sudo ufw allow 3000/tcp
```